# Как можно ускорить работу с БД?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Есть код, который подгружается с помощью JS метода `.load`.

В таблице базы данных 1500 записей.

Проблема в том, что данный код выполняется 12.5 секунд. Как можно ускорить выполнение данного кода?

```
$(".blok1").load("/ajax/blok1.php",function(){
                    
    popups();
    dopfunkcsKl();

});
```

Код файла blok1.php

```
<?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4, text_25, text_26, text_27, text_28 FROM blok1 ORDER BY text_1") or die("Обнаружены следующие ошибки: " . mysql_error());
?>

    <div class="menutable popup-link-9">    
        Add
    </div>
    <?
    if($_SESSION['prava'] < 3)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="menutable deleteClients">   
        Delete
    </div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ckientscheked"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 3
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 4
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 5
            </td>
            <td>
                Text 6
            </td>
            <?
            if($_SESSION['prava'] < 3)
            {
            ?>
            <td style="width: 100px;">
                Text 4
            </td>
            <?
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?
        while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $dobaclass = '';
            if($myrow['text_28'])
            {
                $dobaclass = 'dobavlenoshopsir';
            }
        ?>
        <tr class="<?=$dobaclass;?>">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="ckientscheked"/>
                <input type='hidden' class='idenclient' value='<?=$myrow['id'];?>'>
            </td>
            <td class="leftalignstext namesk">
                <?=$myrow['text_1'];?>
            </td>
            <td class="leftalignstext">
                <?=$myrow['text_2'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$myrow['text_3'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$myrow['text_25'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$myrow['text_26'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$myrow['text_4'];?>
            </td>
            <?
            if($_SESSION['prava'] < 3)
            {
            ?>
            <td class="towari">
                
                <span class='delposclients'>&times;</span>
                
                <span class='upsposclients popup-link-0'>R</span>
                <span class='obzorklients'>O</span>
                
                <?
                if($myrow['text_27'])
                {
                ?>
                <span class='markerpolz'>&reg;</span>
                <?
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <?
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, где возникают тормоза: либо на этапе передачи AJAX ответ, либо на этапе обращений к БД.

Вопрос по базе данных - как быстро выполняется запрос:

    SELECT id, text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4, text_25, text_26, text_27, text_28 FROM blok1 ORDER BY text_1

Comment: Походу, проблема в БД, очень долго все грузиться. Как можно ускорить процесс работы?

Comment: Отображение строк 0 - 1481 (1482 всего, Запрос занял 0.0638 сек.)

Comment: Если проблема в бд, то см. [Поиск узких мест в производительности MySQL: ботанический определитель](http://sqlinfo.ru/a/i/rubtsov_mysqlbot.ppt)